# Prove isometry preserving excision is Killing-like?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, symmetry, vector-fields

(If you think thia is e.g. not well expressed you already understand the request for help.)

**Theorem**: Given a manifold $M$ equipped with a metric $g$ and possessing at least one non-trivial isometry $\phi$ generated by a Killing field $K$, for $M' = M\setminus W$, where $W$ is an open subset in $M$ $\phi:M'\rightarrow M''$ is an isometry if and only if $\forall p \in \partial \overline{W}$, $T_{p}(p)M'$ is parallel to $K(p)$.

**Corollary**: The symmetries of $W$ determine the isometries of $M'$: if tangents to $\partial \overline{W}$ are in $K_i$ everywhere tangent to $\partial \overline{W}$, $K_i$ remains a Killing field of $M'$.

---

If not actually false, this may be known/trivial but I can't find a proof - and I am hampered by lack of knowledge & notation in constructing one (so the statement might not be very good either; conditions on the manifold missing, for example).

Having thought about this in the specific context of the timelike Killing fields of Minkowski space (Lorentzian metric) the general case (Riemmanian or Lorentzian) stated above seemed plausible, but a proof of the special case is what I really need.

**Sketches**. The theorem is that if a region is excised from a manifold, if the boundary of that region follows the integral curves of a Killing field of the original manifold that field is a Killing field of the resulting manifold.

Proof (by contradiction in the case of the timelike Killing fields of Minkowski space... Lorentzian metric). Assume that $\phi: M'\rightarrow M''$ is an isometry; choose a point $p \in \partial \overline{W}$; since $W$ is timelike there is always one Killing vector field $K$ parallel to $T_{p}(p)M'$; choose some other $q \in \partial \overline{W}$, then either the tangent at $q$ is parallel to $K$ or it is not: if it is not, $\partial \overline{W}$ must intersect the integral curves of K and the excision therefore breaks the bijection (by deleting image points) and there can be no isometry at all - a contradiction. Thus $\partial \overline{W}$ must be ruled by the integral curves of K. (Probably needs extending/theorem reformulating for the general case because there's no guarantee that he there is a Killing vector anywhere tangent to the excision boundary)

Pedagogical answers will be doubly welcome - it's one thing to have an answer, another to understand it!

(reposted with minor improvements from math.se)

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2335558/11127

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that your question has not so much to do with Killing fields. It is a more general question. Consider a smooth vector field $X$ over a smooth (Hausdorff) manifold $M$ and suppose that the **one-parameter group of local diffeomorphisms** $\phi$ associated to $X$ is **global** (which is equivalent to saying that $X$ is **complete**). In other words,  if $x\in M$ the differential equation $$\dot{\gamma}_x(t) = X(\gamma_x(t))$$ with initial condition $$\gamma_x(0)=x$$ admits a (unique) maximal solution $\gamma_x= \gamma_x(t)$ defined for *all* $t \in \mathbb R$.

There are sufficient conditions assuring that $\phi$ is global (for instance it happens provided $M$ is compact).

This way, $\phi : \mathbb R \times M \ni (t,x) \mapsto \phi_t(x):= \gamma_x(t) \in M$ is smooth and well-defined. Moreover

(1) $\phi_0 = id$

and

(2) $\phi_t \circ \phi_\tau = \phi_{t+\tau}$ for every $t,\tau \in \mathbb R$.

The case you are considering also requires that $M$ is equipped with a nondegenerate metric $g$ and $X$ is a *complete* $g$-Killing vector field.

In this case every $\phi_t : M \to M$ is an isometry.

Well, coming back to the general case, the following proposition is valid.

**PROPOSITION**. *Let $A \subset M$ be an open set whose boundary $\partial A$ is a smooth codimension-$1$ embedded submanifold of the smooth manifold $M$ and $X$  a smooth complete vector field on $M$.
Then  the following two facts are equivalent.*

*(a) $\phi_t(A) = A$ and  $\phi_t(M\setminus \overline{A}) = M\setminus \overline{A}$ for every $t \in \mathbb R$.*

*(b) $X$ is tangent to $\partial A$.*

**Proof**.

(1) We prove that not (a) implies not (b).

If it is false that $\phi_t(A) = A$ and $\phi_t(M\setminus \overline{A}) = M\setminus \overline{A}$ for all $t$, then  there must exist a point $x_0 \in A$ such that $\phi_{t_0}(x_0) \not \in A$ or a point $x_0 \in M\setminus \overline{A}$ such that $\phi_{t_0}(x_0) \not\in M \setminus \overline{A}$ for some $t_0 \in \mathbb R$. Assume the former is valid (the latter can be treated similarly). Assume $t_0>0$ the other case is analogous. 
There are now two possibilities for  $\phi_{t_0}(x_0) \not \in A$. One is $\phi_{t_0}(x_0)\in \partial A$ and in this case define $s:= t_0$. The other possibility is $\phi_{t_0}(x_0)\in M  \setminus\overline{A}$. In this case, define 
$$s := \sup\{t \in [0,+\infty) \:|\: \phi_\tau(x_0) \in A\:, \quad \tau < t\}\:.$$ This number exists and is finite (because the set  is not empty, as it contains $0$, and $t_0<+\infty$ is an upper bound), strictly positive not greater than $t_0$, and again $\phi_s(x_0) \in \partial A$.

(Indeed, if $\phi_s(x_0)\in A$ there is an open neighborhood of $\phi_s(x_0)$ completely included in $A$ so that $\phi_\tau(x_0) \in A$ also for some $\tau>s$ which is impossible for the very definition of $\sup$, if $\phi_s(x_0)\in M\setminus \overline{A}$, since this set is open, there would be an open neightborhood of $\phi_s(x_0)$ completely included in  $ M\setminus \overline{A}$ so that $\phi_\tau(x_0) \not\in A$ in some $(s-\epsilon, s]$ which is again impossible for the very definition of $\sup$; the only remaining case id $\phi_s(x_0) \in \partial A$.)

Let us prove that such $s$ (in both possibilities) cannot exist if (b) is valid. Indeed, $X|_{\partial A}$ is a well-defined smooth complete vector field on the smooth manifold $\partial A$ and thus the associated  Cauchy problem *over $\partial A$* with initial condition $\dot{\gamma}(s)= \phi_s(x_0) \in \partial A$ at $t=s$  admits a complete solution *completely contained in* $\partial A$ *also for $t<s$*, but this curve now viewed as a integral line of $X$ in $M$ is uniquely determined and we know by hypothesis that *it starts at $x_0 \not \in \partial A$* finding a contradiction.

(2) We prove that not (b) implies not (a).

Let us assume that (b) is false finding that (a) is false as well.
Assume now that there is $x_0 \in \partial A$ such that $X(x_0)$  is transverse to $\partial A$. As $\partial A$ is an embedded smooth manifold, $X$ is smooth and does not vanish at $x_0$, it is not to difficult to prove that there is a coordinate patch $x^1,x^2,..., x^n$ around $x_0$ in $M$ ($n = dim(M)$) such that $x_0 \equiv (0,0,\ldots, 0)$,
$\partial A$ is the portion of the plane $x^1=0$ contained in the image of the chart, and 
the integral 
curves of $X$ are the curves $\mathbb R \ni t \mapsto (t,x^2,\ldots,x^n)$ (see the final **ADDENDUM**). Since the plane separates $A$ from $M \setminus \overline{A}$, it is evident that there are points in $A$ which are moved into $M \setminus \overline{A}$ by $\phi$ and viceversa. Therefore  $\phi_t(A) = A$  and $\phi_t(M\setminus \overline{A}) = M\setminus \overline{A}$ for every $t \in \mathbb R$ is false.

QED

Evidently, if $X$ is a complete Killing field, the result concerns the associated one-parameter group of isometries.

---

**ADDENDUM**. I prove here that

**Lemma**. *If  $S$ is an embedded $n-1$-dimensional smooth submanifold of the $n$-dimensional smooth manifold $M$, and $X$ is a smooth vector field over $M$ which does not vanish at $x_0\in S$ and is not tangent (i.e., is transverse) to $S$ at $x_0$, then there is a coordinate patch $x^1,x^2,..., x^n$ around $x_0$ in $M$  such that $x_0 \equiv (0,0,\ldots, 0)$,
$S$ is the portion of the plane $x^1=0$ contained in the image of the chart, and the integral curves of $X$ are (restrictions around $t=0$ of) the curves $\mathbb R \ni t \mapsto (t,x^2,\ldots,x^n)$.*

**Proof**. As $S$ is embedded, there is a coordinate patch $(U, \psi)$ in $M$ around $x_0\in S$ such that $\psi(S \cap U) = \{ (y^1,\ldots, y^n) \in \psi(U) \:|\: y^1=0\}$  and we can always assume $\psi(x_0)= (0,\ldots,0)$.
Now $X = \sum_a Y^a\frac{\partial}{\partial y^a}$ is such that $Y^1(0,\ldots, 0) \neq 0$ just because $X$ is transverse to $S$ at $x_0$ (the coordinates $y^2,\ldots, y^n$ are coordinates **on** $S$). The integral lines of $X$ in coordinates satisfy  $\frac{dy^a}{dt} = Y^a(y^1(t),\ldots, y^n(t))$. We are free to fix $t=0$ exactly on $S$ for all curves. Now introduce the coordinates $x^2 =y^2,\ldots, x^n=y^n$ on $S$ and write the said integral curves as smooth functions $y^k = y^k(t,x^2,\ldots, x^n)$, where $x^2,\ldots, x^n$ denotes the initial point on $S$ (at $t=0$) of the considered integral curve. The said map is smooth as well known from standard theorems on smooth dependence from initial data of Cauchy problems.
Finally define $x^1=t$. Since the Jacobian matrix $J=[\frac{\partial y^a}{\partial x^b}]$ exactly at $x_0$ satisfies $$\det J(x_0) = \frac{\partial y^1}{\partial t}|_{x_0} = Y^1(0,\ldots, 0) \neq 0$$
Dini's theorem proves that  $x^1=t$, $x^b= y^b$ define an admissible smooth coordinate system in $M$ around $x_0$. In local coordinates $x^1,\ldots, x^n$, the portion of $S$ entering the domain of the coordinates  is still represented by $x^1=0$ (because $x^1=t$ and all integral curves intersect $S$ at $t=0$) and, locally,  the integral curves of $X$ are trivially restrictions around $t=0$ of the curves $\mathbb R \ni t \mapsto (t,x^2,\ldots,x^n)$.

Comment: A quick initial acknowledgment & copious thanks! Will need to study that carefully but will probably accept later.

Comment: Just 1 initial question: Proposition (a) - you're removing the closure of (open) A, yes? Doesn't that leave M without a boundary? I intended A to be removed not its boundary as well. NB if you are available in chat anytime over the weekend please let me know.

Comment: I remove also the boundary. The picture is this way symmetric under swap of A and M. Sorry I am too busy and I cannot chat.

Comment: I added some further details...

Comment: @Julian Moore What about the 50 points of the bounty??

Comment: Though I still have a couple of Q's I've accepted the answer - with many thanks. After some study I find the answer is based in fundamentals of Lie theory... so I have an entree, but I'm still mathematically ignorant so (if you are inclined to answer) Q1 : how does the proof carry over to M\A rather than M\clos(A)? (This is key for me and I don't see how the symmetry of openness between M & A helps.) And the 3 intermediates: "not difficult to prove", "is easy", "trivial" - where might I find (in descending order of importance!) further guidance on filling in the details? Again, my sincere thx!

Comment: Bounty? I thought that was awarded as soon as I accepted. I will check when I get home.

Comment: I enquired about this in meta; whilst it may be that you answer arrived right at the end of the bounty period I consider the fault mine due to ignorance of the details of the bounty process and by way of recompense will offer a further bounty (when I've worked out how to) of 50 since the result is v. important to me & I greatly value your answer; considering the fault to be mine, it will be entirely unconditional but any further input you may offer will be greatly appreciated. Apologies for the inconvenience. I also saw that @Alfred-Centauri has added a further bounty by way of recognition!

Comment: Do not worry. Unfortunately I am being quite busy with several things to add further details to my answer, I will try later (perhaps in the weekend)...

Comment: OK  @Julian Moore I found the time to add some further proofs. Let me know if it is better now...

Comment: You are most kind - and understanding about the bounty issue; I will however persist with that! Your answer is indeed exemplary. I may now be in a position to complete my paper!

Comment: I can only add a bounty when the current bounty expires And it must be double, which I am more than happy to give.

Comment: No problems, I finally obtained the 50 points of the bounty (added by Alfred Centaury) one  is enough!

Comment: Nonetheless... as promised - and as a matter of principle & good faith - I have added my own bounty of 100 for your considerable effort (with *request* but not conditional upon extension to A closed... is it sufficient to say that it follows for A closed by symmetry since which set the boundary belongs to is not relied upon??)

Comment: Please state your query into a clear form and I will try to answer.

Comment: Thank you greatly. I would like to know how the proof of the Proposition can be employed to obtain: the equivalence of: (a') $\phi_t(A) = A$ and  $\phi_t(M\setminus A) = M\setminus A$ for every $t \in \mathbb R$, and (b), for $A \subset M$ an open set. I *think* I see how to do it, but I am far from confident.

Comment: It is clear that (a) -> (a') because, since $A$, $M\setminus \overline{A}$, $\partial A$ are disjoint sets whose union s $M$, per difference  (a) implies $\phi_t(\partial A) \subset \partial A$ and hence $\phi_t(\partial A) =\partial A$ because every $\phi_t$ is bijective. Now suppose that (a') holds. If $X$ is not tangent at  $x_0 \in \partial A$, exploiting the same argument as I used in (2) you can construct a integral line exiting from $A$ passing for $X(x_0)$. So (a') implies in particular that $X$ is tangent to $\partial A$ and so (b) holds, thus (a')->(b) <->(a).

Comment: Summing up (a) -> (a')-> (b) -> (a) and so (a),(a') and (b) are pairwise equivalent.

Comment: Referring to (a)->(a') I was a bit implicit. To be more explicit: as soon as you know that $\phi_t(\partial A) = \partial A$, from the hypothesis (a) you also have $\phi_t(M \setminus A) = \phi_t(M \setminus \overline{A} \cup \partial A) =  \phi_t(M \setminus \overline{A}) \cup \phi_t(\partial A) = M \setminus \overline{A} \cup  \partial A =  M \setminus A$. This complete the proof that (a)-> (a').

Comment: That was what I think I thought ;) Nicely done - and yet again, many thanks!

Comment: "well known from standard theorems on smooth dependence from initial data of Cauchy problems". I would prefer to cite specific theorems with direct application. Or at least to know what counts as 'well known" at this level... (would Cauchy-Kovalevski be one of them?) Can you help with some specifics?

Comment: Well, it is nothing but the theorem I have already used to define $\phi_t(x)$. The solution of a first order differential equation defined by a smooth vector field on a smooth  manifold  is a jointly smooth function of the parameter along solutions and initial condition.

Comment: Hi Valter - a non-technical question if I may; obviously the original claim worked out but I'm curious to assess my "intuition". Would say the proof sketch was also well motivated or did it overlook crucial factors?  (FYI, application to a manifold M: placing a Lorentz signature metric on M  compact is equivalent (see e.g. Geroch J. Math. Phys '67 for details) to placing a continuous vector field on M, so for M a spacelike bounded section of Minkowski spacetime the propositon is directly applicable, as I had hoped!)

Comment: Hi Julian, it was not only a comment I wanted to understand well your original question. However yes, I think your general idea was correct, indeed what I did was nothing but expanding your idea into a more general context. (I am writing from my phone, I hope to be understandable).

Comment: Hi Valter, also on a phone and enjoying a well earned beer! Your earlier comment seems to have disappeared but it's worth saying the "expansion" was well worth it. Nb I didnt mention the parameter because I did not know of 1 parameter diffeomorphisms as such ;) I tend to learn about such things only when I find a need for them, as in this case ;)

Comment: While LaTeXing & reorganising the proof... "Let A⊂M be an open set whose boundary ∂A..." Does that need rephrasing? Boundary of an open set is the empty set, isn't it? Should it refer to the closure? Thx!

Comment: The boundary (or frontier)  of the **open** ball $\{ x \in \mathbb R^n | \: ||x||<1\}$ is $\{ x \in \mathbb R^n | \: ||x||=1\}$ and not the empty set. The boundary of a set may have no intersection with the set itself.

Comment: I did read the wrong statement I quoted somewhere apparently authoritative but I trust you more than "the internet" ;) Thanks

Comment: You probably found the definition of "manifold with boundary", where, by definition, the boundary is part of the set and a precise interplay (not only topological) exists between the bulk and the boundary.  I instead used the general topological definition of boundary which is completely sufficient to tackle your problem.